# flask - sending email on specific condition

Tags: python, flask

I have this script where it sends an email whenever it satisfies the condition. What is wrong with the coding? I've tried to restart the service multiple times but still no result.

Thanks for the help.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
#other imports


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'mail@gmail.com'  # enter your email here
app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = 'mail@gmail.com' # enter your email here
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'password' # enter your password here
mail=Mail(app)
#other parts unnecessary to be posted

@app.route("/")
def tempReading():
    t=open(temp_sensor,'r')
    lines=t.readlines()
    t.close()

    dista=subprocess.check_output('sudo python /home/pi/webserver/sonic.py', shell=True)

    temp_output = lines[1].find('t=')
    if temp_output != -1:
        temp_string=lines[1].strip()[temp_output+2:]
        temp_c=float(temp_string)/1000.0
    elif temp_c>30:
        msg=Message("Temperature Warning", recipients['1234567@sms.clicksend.com'])
        msg.body="Temperature is ",temp_c
        mail.send(msg)
    templateData = {
        'temp': round(temp_c,1),
                'dis': dista
    }
    return render_template('temp.html',**templateData)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want this to be an `if` and not an `elif`

```
temp_c = None
if temp_output != -1:
    temp_string=lines[1].strip()[temp_output+2:]
    temp_c=float(temp_string)/1000.0
else:
    # return an error here if you can't find temp_c?
if temp_c and temp_c>30:
    msg=Message("Temperature Warning", recipients['1234567@sms.clicksend.com'])
    msg.body="Temperature is %d" % temp_c
    mail.send(msg)
```

Comment: when I do that, it returns an error: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no atrribute 'encode'`

Comment: I've edited my answer to account for that bug as well